# SQLite nested query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have been searching for quite some time but did not succeed to figure out how to select the id column from a table where either of the given other columns is not null.

I tried tied a nested query like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM spam_table WHERE (SELECT c.name FROM pragma_table_info('spam_table') c WHERE c.name LIKE '%ham%' OR c.name LIKE '%eggs%') IS NOT NULL
```

Is there any way that the inner `PRAGMA` returns the corresponding column names to be used for the outer query. And how assure the outer query is been put together using `OR`

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that the inner PRAGMA returns the corresponding
>   column names to be used for the outer query.

No. There is no "dynamic" column names (or table names) in sqlite.

One way to do it in python:

- execute the `pragma_table_info` select
- fetch the results
- iterate the results and create the desired sql string
- execute the created sql string

Comment: Good point. But then again, wouldn't it be simpler to get the entire **spam_table** and do the extraction using python. I'll give that a go

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DinoCoderSaurus for pointing out that there is no dynamic column names

The code I am using need some more pythonic style but in fact it I am running

```
for a in spam_table[0]: # Tables Header from the pragma_table_info(spam_table)
    for i in eggs:      # Search terms given by the UI
        if i in a:
            spam_eggs.append(self.spam_table[0].index(a))
```

Now I know which columns to check to extract the `id`